# Use short, int or long for an integer member variable in a class?

Tags: c++, int

For example, I have a class with an integer member

```
class A
{
    int m_index;
    ...
};
```

Assume the index is in the range of short int, which one is best to use: short, int, or long? I am compiling to 64 bit program.

Comment: if you are sure that index is in the range of short int then go for it.

Comment: Use `int` by default, unless you have special reasons to use another type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to stick to `int` (or `unsigned int`), unless you are dealing with a class that is used to instantiate a massive amounts of objects. In that case for memory saving purposes it is better to choose the narrowest type that fits your needs (maybe even use a bit-filed of the appropriate width).

That, of course, assumes that `int` is sufficiently wide for your purposes. Otherwise, you will have to use a larger type.

The same applies to floating-point types. It is a good idea to stick to `double`, unless you have a good reason to use `float` (like, for example, for a field in a massively instantiated class type).

On top of that I personally prefer to use *unsigned* integer types whenever I can, and resort to *signed* integer types only when I have to.

Finally, a higher-level question would be: what kind of index is that? If this is an index that indexes a `std::deque<int>`, for example, then the best type for that index would be `std::deque<int>::size_type` (which is, BTW, unsigned). If this index is supposed to index a built-in array, then `size_t` might be a good candidate. If this index is supposed to index the entire memory, then `uintptr_t` is the best fit.

Comment: "On top of that I personally prefer to use unsigned integer types whenever I can, and resort to signed integer types only when I have to." - FWIW, I disagree with this, as code like `delta = abs(a - b)` doesn't behave as likely intended with `unsigned` and `b > a` - there are many such issues.  In these cases where `int`s known to be bigger than needed, there's no point trying to get that last bit into play at the expense of such error potential.  While I disagree with a lot of what he says on many issues, Lakos covers this in Large Scale C++ Development in tedious detail.

Comment: @Tony D: In my practice, all situations that require crossing over from unsigned to signed arithmetic always stand out like a sore thumb. I have never run into any issues with it.

Comment: That's fair - just that since you were actively making a recommendation in this space thought I'd cite the counter-argument and some reference for those considering the matter.

Answer (score 3):

What about size_t for your purposes (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)? Here (http://www.viva64.com/en/t/0044/) you can find more information about this type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prioritorise reduced memory usage and have many concurrent instances of the object, you could reasonably use `short int`, otherwise - if you want the design of `A` to communicate that any number of elements could be indexed - even if the current uses of `A` only use a relatively small number - use `size_t`.  `int` is a middle ground - big enough to seem unlimited until it breaks, perhaps not for you or not even your application, but when someone casually reuses your `A` for some other app....

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to insulate your class a little bit from future requirements changes, you should:

1. Make sure that `m_index` is a private member.
2. Create a `typedef` and use the `typedef` in your interface and member variable type.

Here's the code:

```
class A
{
    public:
       typedef int IndexType;

       IndexType getIndex() const;
       void setIndex(IndexType index);

    private:
      IndexType m_index;

};
```